# Python: How do I count each number of False occurences between Trues?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

This is a column in my dataframe df:

```
Price  Peak
10     False
15     True
12     False
13     False
12     False
11     False
18     True
13     False
12     False
20     True
```

I want to count the waiting times between Trues. Desired output in this example would be:

[1, 4, 2]

How would I achieve this most efficiently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it /sw

```
peak = [False,True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,True]
out_list = []
iCounter = 0
for _i in range(len(peak)):
    if peak[_i] == True:
        out_list.append(iCounter)
        iCounter = 0
    else:
        iCounter += 1
print(out_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, got the desired result!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get the output by using something similar to -

```
count = 0
output = []
For x in df.peak:
    if x:
        output.append(count)
        count = 0
    else:
        count +=1
```

Basically you iterate over the column and use a counter to keep track of values. at the end of it all, output will be the array that your are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
[
    len(list(b_iter))
    for b, b_iter in itertools.groupby(a)
    if not b
]
```

Where `len(list(b_iter))` is just one way to get the length of an iterator.  There are others, e.g. `sum(1 for x in b_iter)`

Comment: Thanks. I got the desired result from another answer using a counter in a for loop. However, I'm also trying to understand your solution but it's quite hard even with the documentation. If you could provide an example of how to actually implement this I would greatly appreciate it. If not, that's fine too as I got what I need :)